# Rearrange two-dimensional array by array element

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array that is structured like this:

```
image_arrary[[image1.jpg, 1][image2.jpg, 2][image3.jpg, 3]]
```

the inner array elements are image_name and image_order

The user can click a button which will change the order of the images so after a click the array looks like this

```
image_arrary[[image1.jpg, 1][image2.jpg, 3][image3.jpg, 2]]
```

How do I rearrange the array so that the array is ordered by the image_order so it looks like this?

```
image_arrary[[image1.jpg, 1][image3.jpg, 2][image2.jpg, 3]].
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looping through the array?

Comment: @MorganWilde Good god, no. We have algorithms for that. Just use [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and let the JS engine do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Blazemonger does that apply in his case? Sorting `[]` according to `[][1]` elements value.

Comment: @MorganWilde He really wants to sort a one-dimensional array based on the second value of the sub-arrays. The implementation should be trivial.

Comment: @Blazemonger do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: [Read the docs for array.sort at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). They give a good example of how to sort an array of objects; your approach would be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript have a [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method that can take an optional parameter; this parameter is a function where you can define some custom comparison code that helps the `sort()` method determine which array element is the 'greater'. So, for your example, you could do something like this:

```
var inputArray = [
    ['image1.jpg', 1],
    ['image2.jpg', 3],
    ['image3.jpg', 2]
];

inputArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});

/* inputArray is now sorted /*
```

In this example the `a` and `b` parameters of the 'compare function' will be elements of your 'outer' array. Since you have an array of arrays, `a` and `b` will be arrays in the form `['image1.jpg', 1]`. The compare function just checks the second element of these and returns true if the second element in `a` is less than the second element in `b`. This allows the `sort()` method to determine which 'sub-array' in the 'outer' array should come first.

You can see an example of it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FVRf5/).

Comment: my array actually has 10 elements and the image order is element 7, how would this affect the code you have just posted?

Comment: @BarryWatts - Just change the line to read `return a[6] < b[6]` (assuming you mean the *7th* element).

Answer (score 2):

You could do a simple sort:

```
image_array.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a[1] - b[1];
})
```